# More Complete List of CUPS printer-state-reasons

Tags: cups

In [RFC8011](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8011) p.152 there is a common list of state-reasons that a printer can have. In my testing, this list seems to be very incomplete. Is there a more complete list available for CUPS?

Some examples of printer status state-reasons that are not listed:

- cups-waiting-for-job-completed
- offline-report

I'm sure there are many more examples but these are the ones I've found and recorded.

Comment: Isn't this extremely OEM-specific?

Comment: To a degree, maybe, however cups-waiting-for-job-completed doesn't sound OEM to me.

Comment: I'm gonna hazard a guess that this unfortunately falls under the off topic close reason: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: That would be a shame, I already own the CUPS book and have all of the documentation I could find, including this obscure RFC thing (I still don't know what rfc stands for). None of it has a more complete list. Also perusing around the CUPS source code I can verify cups-waiting-for-job-completed is indeed built right into cups. https://github.com/apple/cups/blob/96a5df62355863da266316649f6806e7a887ad7f/scheduler/sysman.c#L875

Comment: RFC is a common acronym for "Request for Comments". It was first used by IETF (*Internet Engineering Task Force*) and IANA (*Internet Assigning Numbers Authority*) to name the series of documents which specify the very foundations of your online life: all the protocols which make up *The Internet*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** M. Sweet was nice enough to provide this list from IANA: https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipp-registrations/ipp-registrations.xml

The [cups source code](https://github.com/apple/cups/blob/master/scheduler/job.c) seems to illustrate quite a few state reasons that don't appear in that RFC.  Since the same author -- [M. Sweet](https://github.com/michaelrsweet) authors both the RFC as well as maintains the CUPS source code, this may be worth file as a bug report on GitHub to see why the two have diverged.

For example, in 2013, [`cups-waiting-for-completed`](https://github.com/apple/cups/commit/581dae2da052286aae0e5e558d31454894853f56#diff-bb6a2a46cb4b3a7012e6afc2d8ef7eb2R2942) was added and about a day later was renamed to [`cups-waiting-for-job-completed`](https://github.com/apple/cups/commit/1e3e80bb39640590a4b0c9ce7d1dd38d2ee6d90d),
 which came 4 years before the latest 2017 release of the RFC.

The RFC mentions the following codes in the following order:

```
none
other
developer-low
door-open
fuser-over-temp
fuser-under-temp
input-tray-missing
interlock-open
interpreter-resource-unavailable
marker-supply-empty
marker-supply-low
marker-waste-almost-full
marker-waste-full
media-empty
media-jam
media-low
media-needed
moving-to-paused
opc-life-over
opc-near-eol
output-area-almost-full
output-area-full
output-tray-missing
paused
shutdown
spool-area-full
stopped-partly
stopping
timed-out
toner-empty
toner-low
```

However the source code of [`job.c`](https://github.com/apple/cups/blob/master/scheduler/job.c) seems to also mention the following statuses (including the two mention in the question).  I think this makes an exhaustive list until more come along.

```
connecting-to-device
offline-report
cups-insecure-filter-warning
cups-missing-filter-warning
cups-remote-aborted
cups-remote-canceled
cups-remote-completed
cups-remote-pending
cups-remote-pending-held
cups-remote-processing
cups-remote-stopped
cups-waiting-for-job-completed
```

As to the best way to track the addition of new keywords, M. Sweet may also be able to provide information on where the new state keywords are derived.  Here's the commit description of what seems to have prompted the `cups-waiting-for-job-completed`.

> `msweet committed on Nov 6, 2013` Dropped "dark wake" support on OS X, which was preventing portables from going to sleep when there was a stuck job. We now use a variation of the CUPS 1.4
>   sleep support to do a cleaner sleep `<rdar://problem/14323704>` Aside from removing all of the power assertions, we now track a new "cups-waiting-for-completed" state keyword that tells cupsd it can SIGKILL a backend without side-effects - then if we are just waiting for the job to complete we can go to sleep immediately.